# Opening a report - time taken

Tags: ms-access, ms-query

I have a query that I timed takes 25 seconds to run (data from the cloud).
When I run a report based on this query using `DoCmd.OpenReport strReport, acPreview, , strWhere` it takes twice as long.

Is this normal, or is there something I should be looking at?

Comment: If you have any sorting in the query, remove it. All sorting should be done in the report.

Comment: No sorting on the query.  I stepped through the code to ensure nothing else was being run - just that one line takes double the time.

Answer (score 0):

The more work you give to the cloud in sorting, filtering, grouping the less time it will take the report to open, try to do the filter in the cloud instead of the report. As a matter of fact try to do everything in a single query at the origin of the data if possible.